# Testing a window.addEventListener in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, karma-jasmine

I have one method that i'm trying to test in angular using jasmine
but i'm not able to trigger the mousse event (when browser back button is clicked)
and here is my code:

```
navigate() {
        window.addEventListener('popstate', (event) => {
            if (event.state['tab'] = 'new-page') {
                window.location.href = 'www.test-this-page.abcd';
            }});
    }
```

I'm trying to find a solution to trigger **window.addEventListener** with specific params when the **navigate** method is called.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it may be difficult to test the window object, since it is a global object. Also, you should not use `addEventListener` in angular. You must use `HostListener` instead. this way, you'd be able to test it easily:

```
@HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
myMethodOnPopstate(event) {
  if (event.state['navigation'] === 'new-page') {
    window.location.href = 'www.test-this-page.abcd';
  }
}
```